# Class is showing up in Listbox and not the actual string value

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, stored-procedures, listbox

Well firstly this is what is what is happening.
[image]

When I select a table from my database from the combo box I want all the column names to appear which they do (Column names are the 'P101','P102' etc ..) but I also want the Extended Property value of each column to appear which for some reason is not displaying.

This is my SP in C#:

```
[Function(Name = "SP_GET_EXTENDED_PROPERTY", IsComposable = false)]
public ISingleResult<StandardDefinition> GetExtendedProperty(
    [Parameter(Name = "@ptableName", DbType = "VARCHAR(50)")] string tableName,
    [Parameter(Name = "@pcolumnName", DbType = "VARCHAR(50)")] string columnName)
{
    IExecuteResult objResult = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()),tableName, columnName);

    ISingleResult<StandardDefinition> objresults = (ISingleResult<StandardDefinition>)objResult.ReturnValue;

    return objresults;
}
```

That Stored Procedure links to this Query in SQL (This query has been tested and works):

```
SELECT value as _value FROM fn_listextendedproperty
(NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Acceptance', 'column', 'P101');
```

The Column name and Tablename i am passing are correct and working after i debug, and the Query in SQL is correct so i dont know what is going wrong this is my C# code for the selection of the Combobox.

```
    foreach (StandardDefinition standardDefinition in _StandardFields)
    {
        _wrapperSD = new WrapperStandardDefinition(Properties.Settings.Default.AppConnectionString,standardName,standardDefinition.Column_name);

        _SD = _wrapperSD.GetStandardQuestion();

        lstQuestions.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} ( {1} ) ", _standardDefinition, standardDefinition.Column_name));
    }

    public ISingleResult<StandardDefinition> GetStandardQuestion()
    {
        _SP = new StoredProcedures(_connection);

        return _SP.GetExtendedProperty(_selectedStandard, _columnName);
    }
```

Comment: Comment as this doesnt answer the question directly.  To make this easier, could you not add this as a property to your StandardDefinition model class, i.e. "Fancy Name" and do the formatting there, that way you can bind directly to it and reuse it across the boundaries of your site or as an extension method.

Comment: @Modika Ahh i see what you mean, the property is already defined in the Standard Definition class but i could do some formatting there.

Comment: Yeah that's it, it would be a property to do some specific things with the properties already in the class it won't be persisted. Just makes cases like this simple and gives you one point to update, because if you use this style of formatting elsewhere you will have to duplicate and it will get smelly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line here:

```
lstQuestions.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} ( {1} ) ", _standardDefinition, standardDefinition.Column_name));
```

`.ToString()` is implicitly being called on `_standardDefinition` when it is passed as a parameter to `string.Format()`. I believe this is what is giving you the class name.

You can either override the `.ToString()` method in the class if you want it to return something different. Or you can pass in the value you want, e.g. `_standardDefinition.MyPropertyWithDesiredValue`, rather than the object itself.

Comment: I just changed my code to fix it e.g _standardDefiniion.Value but i realised Value is NULL. I am going to have to edit my Stored Procedure or find the other error in my code. Thats for the answer, it may not of been the answer but helped me find my problem!

Comment: Glad I could help. Just as a FYI, there is a property called `DisplayMemberPath` on the `ListBox`. So you could add objects of type `StandardDefinition` to the `ListBox.Items`, and the `ListBox` will display the property defined in `DisplayMemberPath`. You can use the `DataTemplate` that Sheridan explained if you want to create a more complex layout.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a custom `StandardDefinition` object to the Framework to display, but you haven't told it how to display it, so WPF uses the name of the type:

```
DAL.Entities.StandardDefinition
```

The quickest and easiest way to display something more meaningful is to simply override the `object.ToString` method, as that is what WPF will attempt to use by default. So if you were to do something like this...:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}: {1}", SomeProperty, SomeOtherProperty);
}
```

... your output could be something like this:

```
Some value: some other value
```

That would probably be fine for a text output, but another option to improve the display of these items would be for you to declare a `DataTemplate` which defines what each item should look like. You could do that something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Entities:StandardDefinition}">
    <!-- Define what the item should look like here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think Darren helped me figure out the problem is that i was calling _standardDefinition but not passing the property e.g. _standardDefinition.value. This is returning NULL which means i have some other errors thanks for explaining as i didnt know about the DataTemplate way around things.

Comment: Not a problem at all... he needs the reputation more than I do anyway.